# Symfony / Doctrine : Last onFlush event with embedded forms

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony, using embedded forms involving several Doctrine entities, I would like to be able to detect the last [onFlush](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush) event (so the last flushed entity) after form submission. My goal is to manipulate some files at this moment.

Is there a way to achieve this easily ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a Listener for `onFlush`, follow the [Symfony documentation for Doctrine listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html).

However, this listener will be called for every `flush` in your application, not only for your particular form! If you only want to execute actions when the form is submitted, maybe you should be looking at [Symfony Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html).

Comment: Thanks but I already have several Doctrine listeners in my application. What I want is to know the last entity flushed (among all the entities flushed after form submission). So I don't want to detect when the form has been submitted (form events) but I want to detect the end of all flushing opérations.

Comment: There is no such thing as flush entity order. Entity are not processed by Doctrine's ORM in the order they are persisted or flushed, so talking about the "last entity flushed" does not make sense. Except if you call `flush` several times in a single action? Even in this scenario, I don't think it is possible to determine if there are still flushes scheduled before the request termination. I think you should consider another implementation than using onFlush events.

Comment: That's what I expected. I agree that I have to find another way to solve my issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You would do better to actually implement a listener on two events... this way at least you know the application is in a shutting down state and everything that can possibly flush has already flushed.

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {

        return [                       
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'doLastFlush',
            ConsoleEvents::TERMINATE => 'doLastFlush',
        ];
    }
```